# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError Message: Too few arguments to function Nilsemhas::detail(), 0 passed in

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem when i'm trying to generated code for detailed feature

Controller :

```
<?php

class Nilsemhas extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['nilsemhas']       = $this->nilsemhas_model->tampil_data()->result();
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/header_lec');
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/sidebar_lec');
        $this->load->view('administrator/nilsemhas', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/footer_lec');
    }

    public function detail($id_nilsemhas)
    {
        $data['detail'] = $this->nilsemhas_model->
                            ambil_id_nilsemhas($id_nilsemhas);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/header_lec');
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/sidebar_lec');
        $this->load->view('administrator/nilsemhas_detail', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/footer_lec');
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        $where = array('id_nilsemhas' => $id);
        $data['nilsemhas'] = $this->nilsemhas_model->edit_data(
            $where,
            'nilsemhas'
        )->result();
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/header_lec');
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/sidebar_lec');
        $this->load->view('administrator/nilsemhas_update', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates_administrator/footer_lec');
    }

    public function update_aksi()
    {
        $id              = $this->input->post('id_nilsemhas');
        $nilsemhas_1     = $this->input->post('nilsemhas_1');
        $nilsemhas_2     = $this->input->post('nilsemhas_2');
        $nilsemhas_3   = $this->input->post('nilsemhas_3');

        $data = array(
            'nilsemhas_1' => $nilsemhas_1,
            'nilsemhas_2' => $nilsemhas_2,
            'nilsemhas_3' => $nilsemhas_3,
        );

        $where = array(
            'id_nilsemhas' => $id
        );

        $this->nilsemhas_model->update_data($where, $data, 'id_nilsemhas');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show"
        role="alert">
       Nilai Seminar Hasil Berhasil Ditambahkan!
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-close" data-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>');
        redirect('administrator/nilsemhas');
    }

    public function _rules()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'nilsemhas_1',
            'nilsemhas_1',
            'required',
            ['required' => 'Wajib Diisi!']
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'nilsemhas_2',
            'nilsemhas_2',
            'required',
            ['required' => 'Wajib Diisi!']
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'nilsemhas_3',
            'nilsemhas_3',
            'required',
            ['required' => 'Wajib Diisi!']
        );
    }
}
```

Model :

```
<?php

class Nilsemhas_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function tampil_data()
    {
        $this->db->select('dfsemhas.nama_mhs_semhas, dfsemhas.nim_semhas, dfsemhas.prodi_semhas, dfsemhas.judul_semhas');
        $this->db->from('nilsemhas');
        $this->db->join('dfsemhas', 'dfsemhas.id_semhas = nilsemhas.id_semhas');
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    public function input_data($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('nilsemhas', $data);
    }

    public function ambil_id_nilsemhas($id_nilsemhas)
    {
        $this->db->select('dfsemhas.nama_mhs_semhas, dfsemhas.nim_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.prodi_semhas, dfsemhas.judul_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.dospem1_semhas, dfsemhas.dospem2_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.dosenuji1_semhas, dfsemhas.dosenuji2_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.komisi_semhas, dfsemhas.tgl_semhas,
                            dfsemhas.waktu_semhas, dfsemhas.tempat_semhas,
                            nilsemhas.*');
        $this->db->from('nilsemhas');
        $this->db->join('dfsemhas', 'dfsemhas.id_semhas = nilsemhas.id_semhas');
        $this->db->where_in('nilsemhas.id_nilsemhas', $id_nilsemhas);
        $hasil = $this->db->get();

        if ($hasil->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $hasil->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function edit_data($where, $table)
    {
        $this->db->select('nilsemhas.*, dfsemhas.nama_mhs_semhas, dfsemhas.nim_semhas, dfsemhas.prodi_semhas, dfsemhas.judul_semhas');
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->join('dfsemhas', 'dfsemhas.id_semhas = nilsemhas.id_nilsemhas');
        $this->db->where($where);
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    public function update_data($where, $data, $table)
    {
        $id_nilsemhas = $where['id_nilsemhas'];
        $dfsemhas = $this->db->where('id_semhas', $id_nilsemhas)->get('dfsemhas')->row();

        $data['nama_mhs_semhas'] = $dfsemhas->nama_mhs_semhas;
        $data['nim_semhas'] = $dfsemhas->nim_semhas;
        $data['prodi_semhas'] = $dfsemhas->prodi_semhas;
        $data['judul_semhas'] = $dfsemhas->judul_semhas;

        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->update($table, $data);

        // Update kolom nama_mhs_semhas, nim_semhas, prodi_semhas, dan judul_semhas di tabel nilsemhas
        $this->db->where('id_nilsemhas', $id_nilsemhas);
        $this->db->update('nilsemhas', $data);
    }
}
```

View :

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
        <h4> <strong>Penilaian Seminar Hasil </strong> </h4>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('pesan'); ?>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hovered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Nama</th>
            <th>NIM</th>
            <th>Program Studi</th>
            <th>Judul</th>
            <th colspan="3">AKSI</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $no = 1;
        foreach ($nilsemhas as $nsh) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="20px"><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($nsh->nama_mhs_semhas) ? $nsh->nama_mhs_semhas : '') ?></td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($nsh->nim_semhas) ? $nsh->nim_semhas : '') ?></td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($nsh->prodi_semhas) ? $nsh->prodi_semhas : '') ?></td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($nsh->judul_semhas) ? $nsh->judul_semhas : '') ?></td>
                <td width="20px">
                    <?php echo anchor(
                        'administrator/nilsemhas/detail/' .
                        (isset($nsh->id_nilsemhas) ? $nsh->id_nilsemhas : ''),
                        '<div class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></div>'
                    ) ?>
                </td>
                <td width="20px">
                    <?php echo anchor(
                        'administrator/nilsemhas/update/' . (isset($nsh->id_nilsemhas) ? $nsh->id_nilsemhas : ''),
                        '<div class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></div>'
                    ) ?>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Detail :

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Data Mahasiswa
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">

        <?php foreach ($detail as $dt) : ?>

            <tr>
                <td>Nama Mahasiswa</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->nama_mhs_semhas) ? $dt->nama_mhs_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>NIM</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->nim_semhas) ? $dt->nim_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Program Studi</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->prodi_semhas) ? $dt->prodi_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Judul Penelitian</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->judul_semhas) ? $dt->judul_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Ketua Komisi Pembimbing</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->dospem1_semhas) ? $dt->dospem1_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Anggota Komisi Pembimbing</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->dospem2_semhas) ? $dt->dospem2_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Dosen Penguji 1</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->dosenuji1_semhas) ? $dt->dosenuji1_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Dosen Penguji 2</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->dosenuji2_semhas) ? $dt->dosenuji2_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Komisi Seminar</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->komisi_semhas) ? $dt->komisi_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tanggal Seminar Hasil</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->tgl_semhas) ? $dt->tgl_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Waktu Seminar Hasil</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->waktu_semhas) ? $dt->waktu_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tempat</td>
                <td><?php echo (isset($dt->tempat_semhas) ? $dt->tempat_semhas : ''); ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

    <?php echo anchor(
        'administrator/nilsemhas',
        '<div class="btn btn-secondary">Kembali</div>'
    ) ?>
</div>
```

I'm trying to open the detailed feature and this error appears

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function Nilsemhas::detail(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\eassessment\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\eassessment\application\controllers\administrator\nilsemhas.php
>
> Line Number: 14
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\eassessment\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please show the code with the call to `Nilsemhas::detail()`, I don't see it in the question. The error message says that the argument is not provided for this method.